# BringIntoViewRequester not working when composable that needs to be bringed into view is resized

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard, input-field

Last few days I'm trying to find a solution for a problem when

> keyboard overlaps text input field in vertical scrollable
> column.

After trying many things, finally found solution where everything is working except in a case where I want to display error validation message under input field when a button is clicked.

In that case bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView() stopped working and onFocusEvent is triggered in a loop.

Here is the code:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
            .imePadding()
            .navigationBarsPadding()
    ) {
        InputField()
        InputField()
        InputField()
            ....
    }
}

@Composable
fun InputField() {
    val bringIntoViewRequester = remember { BringIntoViewRequester() }
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val focusLocalManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    val view = LocalView.current
    val context = LocalContext.current

    WindowInsets.ime
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        ViewCompat.setWindowInsetsAnimationCallback(view, null)
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .bringIntoViewRequester(bringIntoViewRequester)
    ) {
        BasicTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .onFocusEvent { fs ->
                    if (fs.isFocused) {
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
                        }
                    }
                }
            .....
        )
        if (errorMessage.isNotEmpty())
            Text(
                text = errorMessage,
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.error
            )
    }
}
```

Also I setup property in *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

and in *MainActivity*:

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, you just need to put scroll modifier after imePadding modifier. I think that because of available scrolling area.

```
Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .imePadding()
        .verticalScroll(state = scrollState)
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason after adding some delay before bringIntoView() call it work for me

```
.onFocusChanged { focusState ->
                if (focusState.isFocused) {
                    scope.launch {
                        delay(420)
                        bringIntoViewRequester.bringIntoView()
                    }
                }
            }
```

Interesting but 300ms is not enough for this hack :) Maybe this is because of keyboard animation duration

Comment: Did you find any solution to this animation delay? I am having the same problem :/

Answer (score 1):

```
Column(
    Modifier
        .imePadding()
        .fillMaxSize()
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
```

If you want to scroll and maintain the view then you should specify the height also which you can get from `BoxWithConstraints`

Do not forget all three:

1. imePadding()
2. verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
3. height(maxHeight)

Also if you have those lines of Code:

```
    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
    )
```

You have to remove them and find another workaround since they have conflict with bringIntoView

Answer (score 0):

accidentally  added this
`implementation androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.4.3` this dependency after i remove this dependency now it's work

Answer (score 0):

Try use decorationBox property

```
BasicTextField(
    decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
                            //custom UI
                        Box(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize(),
                            contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart
                        ) {
                            //custom UI
                            innerTextField()
                        }
                            //custom UI
                    },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case (using Scaffold), I used innerPadding.calculateTopPadding(), innerPadding.calculateBottomPadding() and AFTER a verticalScroll modifier. And that's how I got it to work well

```
    content = { innerPadding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .padding(
                     top = innerPadding.calculateTopPadding(), 
                     bottom = innerPadding.calculateBottomPadding()
                )
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
        ) {...
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, this is what you need and it works perfectly:

[image]

```kotlin
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
@Composable
fun OutlinedTextFieldValidation(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    readOnly: Boolean = false,
    textStyle: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current,
    label: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    placeholder: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    leadingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    error: String? = null,
    isError: Boolean = error?.isNotEmpty() ?: false,
    trailingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = {
        if (error?.isNotEmpty() == true)
            Icon(Icons.Filled.Warning, "error", tint = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error)
    },
    visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default,
    keyboardActions: KeyboardActions = KeyboardActions.Default,
    singleLine: Boolean = true,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    interactionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small,
    colors: TextFieldColors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
        disabledTextColor = Color.Black
    ),
) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.imePadding(), // <-- this will save your life
    ) {
        OutlinedTextField(
            enabled = enabled,
            readOnly = readOnly,
            value = value,
            onValueChange = onValueChange,
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            singleLine = singleLine,
            textStyle = textStyle,
            label = label,
            placeholder = placeholder,
            leadingIcon = leadingIcon,
            trailingIcon = trailingIcon,
            isError = isError,
            visualTransformation = visualTransformation,
            keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
            keyboardActions = keyboardActions,
            maxLines = maxLines,
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            shape = shape,
            colors = colors,
        )
        if (error?.isNotEmpty() == true) {
            Text(
                text = error,
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.error,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelSmall,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 16.dp, top = 0.dp),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Special thanks to [Rafa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/959470/desgraci)